# Entity Framework shows inconsistent behaviour when used with Asp.net Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

I have 3 tables Violation,Comment and and auto generated AspNetUsers respectively.The relationship between them as follows.

[image]

I am using code-first approach and my models are as follows.Some properties are removed for brevity.

**Violation Model**

```
public class Violation
    {
        public Violation()
        {
            this.Comments = new HashSet<Comment>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser CreatorUser { get; set; }
    }
```

**Comment Model**

```
 public class Comment
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Content { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime PostedDateTime { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public Violation Violation { get; set; }

    }
```

**ApplicationUser(AspNetUsers Table)**

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        this.Comments = new List<Comment>();
        this.Violations = new List<Violation>();

    }
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Violation> Violations { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to retrieve Comment's ApplicationUser navigation property , I see many of them pointing to a null property even database has proper record for each of them.

Shortly,EF doesn't retrieve database records properly.I stuck with it,can't find the reason.

[image: Exception]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is lazy loading enabled?

Comment: Yes , I enabled it.As far as I know it is enabled by default

Comment: By the way,when the user who wrote  the comment logs in the application it fetchs related comment with a not null ApplicationUser property, things become more stranger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, it's *not* being lazy-loaded. You didn't add the `virtual` keyword to your `Comment.ApplicationUser` property, so Entity Framework cannot override it to add the lazy-loading logic. As a result, it's always going to be null unless you explicitly load it. Add the `virtual` keyword, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the navigation properties populated you need to include them in the query:

```
var comments = context.Comments
  .Include(c => c.Violation)
  .Include(c => c.ApplicationUser)
  .Where(x => x.Violation.Id == violationId);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eager

Comment: I don't think Include keyword necessarily needed for Lazy Loading.However It seems I forgot to mark Comment's ApplicationUser  property as virtual as well as violation property.I will mark them as virtual and share results

Comment: OK, if that is your intent, but if you are looping through comments you are going to take a database hit on every reference to the lazy loaded objects. Personally, I have never found a use for lazy loading.

Comment: While the primary issue was the missing `virtual` keyword, @SteveGreene is correct that you'll want to explicitly load it, anyways, for performance reasons. Otherwise, you'll be issuing N+1 queries, as you iterate.